# Accessing AWS bucket with a url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform

I need to do a transfer service from AWS to GCP and I have the following URL and the Access key ID and Secret access key

```
 s3://DataBucket/dataset=location/country=/year=2020/month=04/
```

When I wrote only DataBucket in bucket name and created the transfer service, It gave me an error "Permission denied" so I thought that I have no access to the bucket and only that path, right?

Using AWS CLI when I tried to list objects in that path 0 objects was found and no sub folders

But when I listed folders under dataset=location I have found subfolders as the following country=us,country=are... etc
and when I list objects with one of the countries "s3://DataBucket/dataset=location/country=us/year=2020/month=04/" I can find the files to be transferred

So Any idea where this path (s3://DataBucket/dataset=location/country=/year=2020/month=04/) with only country=/ come from?

And how can I use it for transfer?

Comment: You'll need to ask the owner of the bucket, or keep experimenting to figure out what's there. You haven't told us the bucket name, and we probably don't have access, so we can't really offer any assistance for this.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for your reply, I will ask the owner for more details. but you didn't see a path containing a folder name like this "/country=/ " (it's the common part of all the sub-folders folders under "dataset=location") ?

Comment: It does look strange. It might be for the rows that have `country=NULL`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No, all the subfolders are with name like country=US,country=ARE.. etc no null in them